# Adjusting the values in an array to be at least minimum distance apart

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array of floats in a specific order

```
[99.3, 100.0, 98.6]
```

I need to ensure that they are a minimum distance apart, for this example say they must be at least 3 units apart.  The maximum value should not be adjusted.

The other values can all be adjusted to pass the spacing rule.

Their original values are used to display a percentage, and they should always remain in that order so they match with a graph. The adjusted values will ultimately be mapped to display coordinates (this is why the spacing is important, so items do not overlap)

So far I have:

```py
from copy import copy

def adjust_spacing(values, minimum_spacing):
    output_values = copy(values)
    adjusted_values = []
    adjusted_indexes = []

    max_val = max(values)
    max_val_index = values.index(max_val)

    # Add the maximum value as is
    adjusted_values.append(max_val)
    adjusted_indexes.append(max_val_index)

    current_max = max_val

    while len(adjusted_values) != len(values):
        # Find the next maximum value (excluding the current max) and its index
        next_value = max(val for val in values if val < current_max)
        next_value_index = values.index(next_value)

        # Calculate the adjusted next value
        adjusted_next_value = current_max - minimum_spacing

        adjusted_values.append(adjusted_next_value)
        adjusted_indexes.append(next_value_index)

        current_max = adjusted_next_value

    while len(adjusted_values) > 0:
        value = adjusted_values.pop()
        index = adjusted_indexes.pop()
        output_values[index] = value


    return output_values

result = adjust_spacing([99.0, 100.0, 95.0], 4)
print(f"=> {result}")
```

and when run I get:

```py
values = [99.3, 100.0, 98.6]
minimum_distance = 4
adjust_spacing(values, minimum_distance)
=> [96.0, 100.0, 92.0]
```

While that's correct, surely there is a better, more idiomatic way to do this.

It'd be even better if it worked with a larger array. (this breaks with len > 3... oof!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will achieve what you want:

```py
import numpy as np

def adjust_spacing(arr, minimum_spacing):
    arr = np.array(arr)

    reversed = sorted(arr, reverse=True)

    adjusted = reversed[0:1]
    for num in reversed[1:]:
        bar = adjusted[-1] - minimum_spacing
        adjusted.append(num if num < bar else bar)

    return list(np.array(adjusted)[np.argsort(np.argsort(-arr))])

result = adjust_spacing([99.0, 50, 51, 52, 100.0, 95.0], 4)
print(f"=> {result}")
```

Comment: Could you wrap that in a function and also include the imports you'd need? Thank you.  Does it work with more than 3 values in the list as that's a pretty terrible limitation of my function!

Comment: Yes, I tested it on more than 3 items. It only uses numpy.

Comment: Tests are green, Nice work! I made a few amendments so that the input and output are agnostic of numpy, so it can adhere to the original fn signature for the question and get the green checkmark.